# list printing brackets within the output

Tags: python, arrays, list

here is my code

```
old_lists = [['one', 'two', ['three', 'four', 'five']], 
['six', 'seven', ['eight', 'nine', 'ten']], 
['eleven', 'twelve', ['thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']]]

new_list = []

for i, j, k in old_lists:
    new_list.append(i, j, k)

print(new_list)
```

I am getting this output

```
one two ['three', 'four', 'five']
six seven ['eight', 'nine', 'ten']
eleven twelve ['thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']
```

I would like the below output

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
['six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']
```

Comment: Can you state the actual complete output you want? It's a bit unclear the way the question is worded.

Comment: Pls show your expected `output result`

Comment: I would like three lists not lists within lists

Comment: expected output will be as ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
['six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = []

for i, j, k in old_lists:
    new_list.append( [i,j]+k )

print(new_list)
```

Or even better:

```
new_list = [ [i,j]+k for i,j,k in old_lists ]
```